# Validating & Converting pdf file type to base 64

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this tutorial to create a drag and drop interface in React. In the tutorial, the valid file types are for images.

`const validTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/x-icon'];`

However, since I am customizing my component, I want to use PDF and convert it to base64.

**Validate Files**

```
  const validateFile = (file) => {
    const validTypes = ['file/pdf'];
    if (validTypes.indexOf(file.type) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log('valid?', validateFile);
    return true;
  };
```

**uploadFiles** function

```
  const uploadFiles = () => {
    uploadModalRef.current.style.display = 'block';
    uploadRef.current.innerHTML = 'File(s) Uploading...';
    for (let i = 0; i < validFiles.length; i++) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', validFiles[i]);
      axios
        .post('/data', formData, {
          onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            const uploadPercentage = Math.floor(
              (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100
            );
            progressRef.current.innerHTML = `${uploadPercentage}%`;
            progressRef.current.style.width = `${uploadPercentage}%`;
            if (uploadPercentage === 100) {
              uploadRef.current.innerHTML = 'File(s) Uploaded';
              validFiles.length = 0;
              setValidFiles([...validFiles]);
              setSelectedFiles([...validFiles]);
              setUnsupportedFiles([...validFiles]);
            }
          },
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // If error, display a message on the upload modal
          uploadRef.current.innerHTML = `<span class="error">Error Uploading File(s)</span>`;
          // set progress bar background color to red
          progressRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        });
    }
  };
```

I've never done this but I assumed that for PDF would be ```'file/.pdf``.
This however always returns an invalid file type. This article [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-type-validation-while-uploading-it-using-javascript/#:~:text=Using%20JavaScript%2C%20you%20can%20easily,complete%20file%20type%20validation%20code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-type-validation-while-uploading-it-using-javascript/#:%7E:text=Using%20JavaScript%2C%20you%20can%20easily,complete%20file%20type%20validation%20code). discusses file type validation, but again it is for images.

How can I check that I have the correct file type and convert it to base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your validTypes array you must include the standard mimetype used for pdfs. According to [rfc3778](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778.txt) it is application/pdf.

And to convert a string to base64, you can use the javascript helper function `btoa('my_string');`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Keimeno. This is the correct answer and I am able to get back base64 data from my pdf.